# Hard time with making a console menu system in java

Tags: java, menu, console, console-application, menu-items

I know there are several ways to create a menu system in Java, such as: using if statements or references and so on ...

The problem is I can't think of the most effective way to create a menu system that will also be easy to change, also efficient, understandable and possible  perform actions from it.

In short, this topic really confuses me, and it is even difficult for me to explain it.  I would like if anyone could help me sort my head out.

Comment: My suggestion is to stop worrying about the best way of doing it and just write your program.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thx.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Everyone can contribute and make your code better...

Comment: @mlwn right, Good idea. I will upload code with a question when I finish writing it.